# Standard Error Reporting

Tags: c, standards, gnu

Common programs like gcc, rm, cp etc. seem to follow a pattern in reporting their errors like this:

program: error

For instance:

```
$ gcc
gcc: no input files
```

Is there some standard function or macro I should call from within my own C programs to report errors in a standard fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no macros (that I know of).  But, here's the relevant [standard](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Errors) for formatting error output.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not aware of [`perror`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/perror/) and `strerror` (etc.), they're worth knowing about. They're not universal by any means, but can be helpful under at least some circumstances.

Comment: Also http://libexplain.sourceforge.net/ if you find perror/strerror still too cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

It dates back to the earliest days of Unix programming.  It was always a recommendation that error messages be prefixed by the name of the command generating them, not least so that if errors occur in a pipeline of commands, you can tell which of the various commands generated the error message.  You can see the style in K&R 1st Edition, in some of the example programs (not quite all), and also in 'Software Tools' by Kernighan & Plauger, and in 'The UNIX Programming Environment' by Kernighan & Pike.

There are no completely standard tools - functions or macros - for such error messages.  (I have an extensive and comprehensive set of error reporting functions that do print the program name ahead of the message.)